# Deploy Windows Store App (C#) for several customers

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-store-apps

How I can distribute my windows 8 store application for several customer?

I know that I should use the sideloading mode, but I  think this is for single user or all user in a single device. Is there something like ClickOnce for this purpose? I need to provide updates each certain time. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't want to go via the store for some reason?

Comment: Yes. This app es for a specific company

Comment: Have you taken a look through this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx

Comment: yes!. In this moment the process is very slow, because I should install app for each customer with this command: add-appxpackage C:\Contoso App\ExpenseS.appx. When I want to update the app, I have uninstall and reinstall the app. I don't understand installation via windows images